# Calculating the area of the parallelogramm given $4$ vertices.

Tags: geometry

I want to calculate the area of a parallelogramm given the following four vertices:

$$\vec{p}=\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 0\\3 \end {pmatrix},\vec{q}=\begin{pmatrix}8 \\ 1\\1 \end {pmatrix},\vec{r}=\begin{pmatrix}6 \\ -2\\-1 \end {pmatrix},\vec{s}=\begin{pmatrix}12 \\ -1\\-3 \end {pmatrix}$$

I know I need to find two sides of the parallelogramm and then take the magnitude of the cross product. Here is my problem:

Assume that I chose to compute $\vec{q}-\vec{p}$ and $\vec{s}-\vec{p}$. My picture could look like this:

[image]

However, since I don't know the spatial location of $p,q,r,s$ then the picture could also look like this:

[image]

So how do I determine which points to subtract in order to get the correct pair of vectors? Does it even matter which pair I take or will the area be the same because of the symmetry of the problem?

Comment: If the first picture is correct, then $\vec{r}=\vec{q}+\vec{s}-\vec{p}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter.
Either way gives you the same value.

For your second drawing, move the top half of the parallelogram to the right of the lower half.
It's the same area.

Comment: Of course! I don't know why I didn't see that. Thank you very much for your help!